# @apply is not supported within nested at-rules like @mixin

Tags: sass, tailwind-css, postcss

I'm trying to apply Tailwind classes to `@mixin` which is `@include` in a CSS selector as follows:

```scss
@mixin card ($shadowColor) {
    @apply p-4 m-4 shadow-xl $shadowColor;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#works {
    @apply text-center;

    & #works-list {
        @apply grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:lg:grid-cols-4 md:lg:gap-4;

        & article {
            @include card ('shadow-green-600');
            @include font-anironc;

            @apply flex items-center justify-center;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have the following error:

```
CssSyntaxError ... @apply is not supported within nested at-rules like @mixin.
```

I checked upon the [Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting) and this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/4995) but I could not make it work nor I am sure of how to un-nest these rules.

Here my postcss.config.js file:

```js
module.exports = {
    parser: "postcss-scss",
    plugins: {
        "postcss-import": {},
        "tailwindcss/nesting": "postcss-nesting",
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
        "@csstools/postcss-sass": "./src/css/style.scss",
    },
};
```

How may I make it work ?

I'll give you a bit more context, it's an educational project in which we have to mix PostCSS and Tailwind even if it's not recommended.

Feel free to ask me further information.

Comment: [Related GH issue](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/7683)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider compiling the SCSS before Tailwind sees it by reorganizing the order of the PostCSS plugins:

```js
plugins: {
  "@csstools/postcss-sass": "./src/css/style.scss",
  "postcss-import": {},
  "tailwindcss/nesting": "postcss-nesting",
  tailwindcss: {},
  autoprefixer: {},
},
```

Or perhaps

```js
plugins: {
  "postcss-import": {},
  "@csstools/postcss-sass": "./src/css/style.scss",
  "tailwindcss/nesting": "postcss-nesting",
  tailwindcss: {},
  autoprefixer: {},
},
```

Depending on whether you want `@csstools/postcss-sass` or `postcss-import` to resolve `@import`s.

---

For your information, it is completely fine that you use Tailwind with PostCSS – Tailwind is a PostCSS plugin! As per [their documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#using-sass-less-or-stylus), it's Sass that is not recommended to be used in conjunction with Tailwind:

> For the best development experience, we highly recommended that you [use PostCSS exclusively](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#using-post-css-as-your-preprocessor), and that you don’t use preprocessors like Sass or Less in your Tailwind projects.

Comment: Yes you are rigth, I confused both. I reorganized the order and it works fine now, thanks !